# Time Complexity of a Naive Solution to Merge K Sorted Arrays

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, runtime-analysis

There is a [leetcode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-k-sorted-lists/) about merging k sorted arrays. I would like to be able to explain the time complexity of the following **naive** solution:

```
function mergexsSortedArrays(xs) {
  if (xs === null || xs.length === 0) {
    return [];
  }

  let l1 = xs[0];

  for (let i = 1; i < xs.length; i++) {
    let l2 = xs[i];

    l1 = merge(l1, l2);
  }

  return l1;
}


/*
This is simply for completeness; the relevant code is above
/*
function merge(l1, l2) {
  const ans = [];

  let l1HeadIdx = 0;
  let l2HeadIdx = 0;

  while (l1HeadIdx < l1.length && l2HeadIdx < l2.length) {
    if (l1[l1HeadIdx] < l2[l2HeadIdx]) {
      ans.push(l1[l1HeadIdx]);
      l1HeadIdx++;
    } else {
      ans.push(l2[l2HeadIdx]);
      l2HeadIdx++;
    }
  }

  while (l1HeadIdx < l1.length) {
    ans.push(l1[l1HeadIdx]);
    l1HeadIdx++;
  }

  while (l2HeadIdx < l2.length) {
    ans.push(l2[l2HeadIdx]);
    l2HeadIdx++;
  }

  return ans;
}
```

Let's say that `k` is the number of elements in the input array. To simplify the math, we will assume that each sorted array has length `n`.

Within the for loop, we are running the merge algorithm. On the first iteration, `l1` will have length `n` and `l2` will have length `n`, so the merge algorithm will be do `2n` work. In the second iteration, `l1` will be `2n` and `l2` will be `n`, so merge will do `3n` work. As our result, the amount of work that is being done in our for loop will be `2n + 3n + 4n ... (k - 1) n`. If we expand this work a bit, it would be `n + 2n + 3n ... k(n)`, and this can be re-written as `n * (1 + 2 + 3 ... k)`; the inner sum has a closed-form formula of `[k * (k + 1)] / 2`, which is essentially an `O(k^2)`, and then we add the `n` to get a final time complexity of `O(n(k^2))`.

Is this correct? Or have I gone off the rails?

Comment: Looks right to me.